# Using NLog to Store Logs conditionally in MongoDB

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I am using Nlog To write logging to several Targets at the same time:
File + Console.
to do that I am using a single line like:
`logger.write("some text");`
So a new line will be added to File and Console.

Now, I would like to add one more target : MongoDB but with a conditional writing meaning a new record should be added to MongoDb only with a 'true' flag like:

`logger.write("some text", IsWriteToMongo);`

I except by doing this line that:

- A new line added to File
- A new line added to Console
- A new record will be added to MongoDb only if IsWriteToMongo = 'true'

how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

NLog is very good at redirecting output based on Logger-names. Maybe consider using Logger-name to control whether output should target MongoDb:

Example code:

```cs
var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Default");
var loggerMongoDb = LogManager.GetLogger("Default.MongoDb");
if (IsWriteToMongo)
   loggerMongoDb.Info("Write To MongoDb");
else
   logger.Info("Not for MongoDb");
```

Example NLog logging-rules (All loggers with suffix `.MongoDb` should write to `mongoDb`-target):

```xml
<rules>
   <logger name="*.MongoDb" minLevel="Info" writeTo="logfile, console, mongoDb" finalMinLevel="Off" />
   <logger name="*" minLevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile, console" />
</rules>
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages